# regex to only allow a range of doubles

Tags: java, regex

I have a `TextField` where the input should be limited between 1.00 and 5.00.
I tried `"\\d+\\.\\d+"`, `[0-9]{1,5}(\.[0-9]+)?` but neither worked, understandably.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a number input? You can set min and max ranges; along with steps.

Comment: Could you show me how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in a comment, there are input field types that will do this check for you. Answering your literal question, however, you can use this:

```
^([1-4]\.[0-9]{2})|(5\.00)$
```

You need to handle the 5.00 end of the range specially.

Comment: If you could refer me to where i could find more information about 'input field types'. I haven't managed to find anything useful on google. I'm working on a JavaFX project.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Answer (score 2):

If you need double on exactly 2-digit precision you can use

```
^[1-5]{1}\.[0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: This allows 5.99, which is outside of OP's range.

Comment: You right,I totally forgot about that!  i saw you answer

Answer (score 1):

```
^[1-4](\\.\\d{1,2})?|5(\\.0{1,2})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

This will validate 1.00 to 5.00 to two decimal places.

```
^([1-4]\\.[0-9]{2})$|(5\\.00)$
```

Example

```
          // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
          String line = "1.00";
          String pattern = "^([1-4]\\.[0-9]{2})$|(5\\.00)$";

          // Create a Pattern object
          Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

          // Now create matcher object.
          Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
          if (m.find( )) {
             System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
          }else {
             System.out.println("NO MATCH: " + line);
          }

          line = "5.0000";
          m = r.matcher(line);
          if (m.find( )) {
             System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
          }else {
             System.out.println("NO MATCH: " + line);
          }
```